# ELKI and ARFF files

Tags: arff, elki

I compare my results against a result-base, but keep on getting different results than the resultbase, even though I have their data.

I wonder if it is hard to get the same results and why, maybe because they invoked it from a java programme and I do it in the GUI and with ARFF files, which should be troublesome and not developed at right now.

My question is - The results of a AUCROCcurve made from ELKI - would the result vary, if I invoked it from a java programme and not as I  do now from the GUI. I would like to get precise results and know I do it right.

Comment: Don't put two questions into one, and don't assume we know what you are talking about, who "their" result is...how should we help you then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Results from the MiniGUI *are* precise.

The UI is an assistant for building a command line, but that doesn't introduce any imprecision. It may introduce some performance cost when e.g. `-verbose` is used. The visualization may cause memory problems *after* the algorithm has finished.

Obviously, the input format (CSV; ARFF) shouldn't have any impact on the outcome. Unless you introduce incorrect additional columns, e.g. an `id` column that should not be used for analysis...